# Views different image styles depending on URL

Tags: views, media

I want get very close Views results, but image style should differ. 
It should be done by using different URLs or Views arguments.
How I can reach that?

**UPD:** final solution:

```
/**
 * Return actual image_style of image depending on URL params.
 */
function _MYMODULE_image_style() {
  $allowed_image_styles = array('image_style_1', 'image_style_2');
  $params = drupal_get_query_parameters();
  if (isset($params['image_style']) && in_array($params['image_style'], $allowed_image_styles)) {
    $image_style = $params['image_style'];
  }
  return isset($image_style) ? $image_style : NULL;
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_views_pre_execute().
 */
function MYMODULE_views_pre_execute(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'view_1' && $view->current_display == 'services_1') {
    $image_style = _mymodule_image_style();
    if ($image_style) {
      $field_name = 'field_vendor_logo';
      $view->display_handler->handlers['field'][$field_name]->options['settings']['image_style'] = $image_style; // <<< THIS IS the main part of solution
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Create your default Views display, then clone it and change the path and the image style accordingly.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but is there any other solution?
Because in this case I should duplicate each of my Views (I have several).

Comment: I guess there is no other way by just using Views UI. Of course, you can try to write a custom module using the views preprocess hooks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create different ImageStyles, If the image field of the content type is `field_image` then you can use this code:

```
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][]='THE_THEME_HOOK_SUGGESTION';
        $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node',$variables['node']);
        $photo_field = $wrapper->field_image->value();
        $url = arg(1); // you can distinguish the address by arg(0),arg(1), ... 
        if ($url == "URL1") {
                $variables['image'] = theme('image_style',
                     array(
                        'style_name' => 'STYLE1',
                        'path' => $photo_field['uri'],
                    )
                );
        } else if ($url == "URL2"){
                $variables['image'] = theme('image_style',
                     array(
                        'style_name' => 'STYLE2',
                        'path' => $photo_field['uri'],
                    )
                );
        }
```

Make sure to put such code `hook_preprocess_node`, and also this code is run when the correspondent content type is loaded. then in the THEME_HOOK page of the content type use `$image` variable to display the image.